# realizar update si un Query genera error en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sintaxis

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado que ejecuta varias consultas a diferentes tablas

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "informix".pr_ventasVsSaldos ()
```

Esto se ejecuta para base de datos de cliente los cuales manejan muchos datos.
En ocasiones por el volumen de datos genera errores de bloqueo.

¿Hay alguna forma de  validar que cuando se genere algún error en algunas de las consultas pueda realizar un update? Esto debido a que cuando se ejecuta el procedimiento es porque previamente en una tabla se envía un parámetro en 1 y esto bloquea un boton de `x` formulario para que no se envie mas peticiones mientras ya se esta ejecutando. Cuando finaliza el procedimiento el sistema realiza un update al parámetro.

```
UPDATE ventas_saldos SET sw_genera_consulta=0
    WHERE  sw_genera_consulta=1;
```

Deseo tener la forma de que si se presenta algún error en cualquiera de las consultas haga lo mismo para que así el formulario quede nuevamente habilitado.

Lo intente de la siguiente forma pero no me funciona, con la función `RAISE EXCEPTION`, si genera error que realice el update indicado

```
ON EXCEPTION SET esql, eisam, estring
        ROLLBACK WORK;
        RAISE EXCEPTION esql, eisam, estring;


UPDATE ventas_saldos SET sw_genera_consulta=0
    WHERE  sw_genera_consulta=1;

        RETURN 0;
        END EXCEPTION
```

Hay alguna otra forma de tener este control.

Comment: cuando dices que no te funciono, que estas queriendo decir? que cosa no funciono?

Comment: No realizo el update, si me genera error no realiza el cambio indicado para liberar el formulario.

Comment: ¿No deberías realizar el `update` antes del `RAISE EXCEPTION ...`?